# PHP - função em plugin próprio WordPress causando erro 500

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Desenvolvi um plugin próprio para inserção de shortcodes no WordPress. Foi meu primeiro, para uso pessoal, esteve funcionando por anos.

Mas há algumas semanas, passou a causar erro 500 (POST wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500) ao tentar fazer a inserção de imagens no editor de artigo. Consigo fazer o upload do arquivo, mas ao clicar em Adicionar mídia e escolher alguma, nada - e dá o erro no console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ativando o debug.log, tenho isso:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function give_linked_media(), 3 passed in
>   /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286 and at least 7 expected in
>   wp-content/plugins/tt-shortcodes/tt-functions.php:205

Essa é a função da linha 205:

```
function give_linked_media( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ) {
    // only if user is sending video or image
    if ( ( wp_attachment_is( 'video', $id ) ) || ( wp_attachment_is_image( $id ) ) ) {

        // build datatype var   
        if ( wp_attachment_is( 'video', $id ) ) {
            $datatype = ' data-lightview-type="iframe" ';
        } else if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $id ) ) {
            $datatype = ' data-lightview-type="image" ';
        } else { }

        // setting lightview params
        if ( empty( get_post_meta( $id, "pop_title", true ) ) ) {
            $poptitle = '';
        } else {
            $poptitle = ' data-lightview-title="' . get_post_meta( $id, "pop_title", true ) . '"';
        }
        if ( empty( get_post_meta( $id, "pop_caption", true ) ) ) {
            $popcaption = '';
        } else {
            $popcaption = ' data-lightview-caption="' . get_post_meta( $id, "pop_caption", true ) . '"';
        }
        if ( empty( get_post_meta( $id, "pop_group", true ) ) ) {
            $popgroup = '';
        } else {
            $popgroup = ' data-lightview-group="' . get_post_meta( $id, "pop_group", true ) . '"';
        }

        // if user decided to don't use, don't replace original html
        $tha_meta = get_post_meta( $id, 'lightbox_on', true );

        // regex bad, DOM good
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/3820783/2234159
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML( $html );
        // get the link rel
        foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'a' ) as $node ) {
            $therel = $node->getAttribute( 'rel' );

            // get the attachment val, if exists
            $therel = explode( ' ', $therel, 2 );
            $therel = $therel[ 0 ];
        }

        if ( $tha_meta == '1' ) { // is checkbox was set
            if ( $therel == 'attachment' ) { // if yes, no candy for you
                $html2 = $html;
            } else { // no attachment? Oh yeah
                $html2 = preg_replace( '/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 class="lightview"' . $poptitle . $popcaption . $popgroup . $datatype . 'fufu="' . $therel . '">', $html );
            }
        } else { // no checkbox? No candy
            $html2 = $html;
        }
    } else {
        $html2 = $html;
    }

    return $html2;
}
add_filter( 'media_send_to_editor', 'give_linked_media', 10, 8 );
```

Comment: Você fez alguma modificação no código fonte do WordPress?

Comment: Nenhuma. Mas pelo que estou lendo em outro lugar, pode ser causado por atualização do PHP de 5.6 para 7.*; usei o EasyApache pra isso há alguns dias, de fato. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099437/error-only-with-php-7-1-how-to-solve-the-too-few-arguments-to-function-get-quer

Comment: Sugestão: Seu diretório https://memoriabit.com.br/wp-includes/ e o diretório https://memoriabit.com.br/wp-content/uploads/ estão descobertos e podem apresentar risco a seu site, crie um arquivo .htaccess e coloque o seguinte código **<Directory “/var/www/html/teste”>Options -Indexes</Directory>**

Comment: Boa, feito. E acabei descobrindo a resposta da pergunta...

Comment: Considere comentar a solução de seu problema com uma resposta, isso poderá ajudar outros usuários:D

Comment: Sim, só estou garantindo com uns testes aqui e já atualizo.

Answer (score 1):

Foi só dar um valor à cada var no início da função. Em vez de:

```
function give_linked_media( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' )
```

Ficou:

```
function give_linked_media( $html = '', $id = '', $caption = '', $title = '', $align ='', $url = '', $size = '', $alt = '' )
```

Resolvido.